# How to get all the neihbors neighbors of a point in a 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to get all the neighbors of a combination of simple one character strings in a 2d array. Meaning, my output looks like this currently in a 3x5:

```
A B C
D E F
A S D 
F S A
G S A
```

So the neighbor of (1,0) should be = A B E S A .
Currently I have the following:

```
public void getNeighborsOfPoint(int x, int y) {

        for (int xx = -1; xx <= 1; xx++) {
            for (int yy = -1; yy <= 1; yy++) {
                if (xx == 0 && yy == 0) {
                    continue; // You are not neighbor to yourself
                }
                if (Math.abs(xx) + Math.abs(yy) > 1) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (isOnMap(x + xx, y + yy)) {
                    System.out.println(grid[x+xx][y+yy]);
                }
            }
        }
   

 public boolean isOnMap(int x, int y) {
        return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < length && y < width;
    }
```

However it is only returning A E A in the example I provided.(it is not returning the ones cross-wise)
What is the right code to make it work? **Note that the input will not always be 3 x 5. It may be a lot of different combination of x and y s.**

Comment: `A B E S A` would be the neighbors of the `D` at `(x,y) = (0,1)`, not the `B` at `(1,0)`, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're not getting the diagonals in your current group is that second `if` statement. You need to cover, for example, `(2, 1)` which is when `xx` is `1` and `yy` is `1`. But `abs(1) + abs(1) = 2` and `2 > 1`, so you don't include it.

As a refactoring exercise, it might be a little cleaner if you have the inside of that for loop simplified to one conditional.

```
if (expression) { 
    continue 
}; 
// other stuff
```

is equivalent to

```
if (!expression) {
  // other stuff.
}
```

And for you, `expression` (in psuedocode) is `not(xx=0 and yy=0) and isOnMap(xx, yy)`

Comment: Just remove the second if statement. What is it supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 2):

The diagonals aren't included because of this code:

```
if (Math.abs(xx) + Math.abs(yy) > 1) {
    continue;
}
```

When it's on the diagonal `Math.abs(xx) == 1 && Math.abs(yy) == 1`. So their sum will be greater than 1. You're skipping over the diagonals by having this code here.

Answer (score 0):

In a loop, the *continue* keyword means that you will skip to the next iteration of the loop. In your case, you have :

```
            if (Math.abs(xx) + Math.abs(yy) > 1) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isOnMap(x + xx, y + yy)) {
                System.out.println(grid[x+xx][y+yy]);
            }
```

So if the first condition is verified, you will not print any answer, meaning that your program won't consider A(xx, yy) to be a neighbord.

In your ABESA example, B and S are ignored because of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 2d arrays with variable number of rows and columns you have to pass them as parameters in your's `isOnMap` method like below:

```
public static boolean isOnMap(int x, int y, int length, int width) {
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < length && y < width;
}
```

You can handle the special cases of your 2d array (when one or both rownumber and columnnumber of your element are equal to 0) rewriting your `getNeighborsOfPoint` method in this way:

```
public static void getNeighborsOfPoint(int x, int y, char[][] grid) {
    final int length = grid.length;
    final int width = grid[0].length;

    if (isOnMap(x, y, length, width)) {

        for (int i = Math.max(0, x - 1); i < Math.min(length, x + 2); ++i) {
            for (int j = Math.max(0, y - 1); j < Math.min(width, y + 2); ++j) {

                if (i != x || j != y) {
                    System.out.println(grid[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```